# Html hyperlink title not showing

Tags: python, html, pandas

what could be the reason the HTML Link title is not showing up properly?

```
df[0].apply(lambda s: f"<br> <a href={s}> Link </a> </br>")
```

every row of my dataframe contains a hyperlink. When sending the email, the hyperlink actually shows up and it is clickable, but it appears the whole link and I want only to appear "Link"

the output I am getting currently:

```
<br> <a href="www.example.com"> Link </a> </br>
```

desired output in html mail:

```
Link
```

Comment: Your problem is with your email (which you just added a mention of), not your link generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `''` for correct string:

```
df[0].apply(lambda s: f"<br> <a href='{s}'> Link </a> </br>")
```

Possible solution:

```
df[0].style.format(lambda s: f"<br> <a href='{s}'> Link </a> </br>")
```

Comment: thanks, I tried it but happens the same. It is showing the whole html snippet: <br> <a href="www.example..com"> Link </a> </br>

Comment: see my edit :))

Comment: with style.format the html tags dissapears correctly . But the hyperlink title "Link" still not showing. Almost there!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
print.text(xyz)
```

This will show you the text. .text() converts HTML code into normal text.

Comment: could you put an example?

Comment: `x = your html code
y = str(x)
print(y)`